# ¿Como evitar el cierre de una app al pulsar enter con un editText vacío?

Tags: android

Buenas, he empezado hace poco en Android y actualmente estoy haciendo una app de adivina un número aleatorio.
Toda la parte del adivinar lo tengo en un método y para que se ejecute lo he llamado en un keyEvent, al pulsar enter se ejecuta el metodo.

```
ed.setOnKeyListener(new android.view.View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, android.view.KeyEvent event) {
             if ((event.getAction() == android.view.KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                adivinar();
                return true;
            } else
                return false;
        }
    });
```

El problema es que si no pongo ningún número en el edtiText y pulso enter, se detiene la aplicación.

He intentado pone una condicional tanto dentro del método adivinar como en el método de keyEvent para que cuando el editText esté en blanco muestre un toast con un mensaje, pero sigue cerrandose la aplicacion.
¿Alguien podría echarme una manilla?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: seria de ayuda si subes el codigo de error que te genera cuando se cierra tu app

Comment: Y algo del metodo adivinar tambien..

Comment: Agrega tu LogCat, me parece algo amplia tu pregunta porque puede haber  varias soluciones además de las que agregaron los compañeros.

Answer (score 1):

Usa *Try-catch*:

```
ed.setOnKeyListener(new android.view.View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, android.view.KeyEvent event) {
    try {
             if ((event.getAction() == android.view.KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                adivinar();
                return true;
            } else
                return false;
        }
} catch(NumberFormatException e){
     textInC.setText("Error!");

}
    });
```

**ó** valida tu **`Edittext`**

```
ed.setOnKeyListener(new android.view.View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, android.view.KeyEvent event) {
    if (ed.matches("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Campo vacío, ingresa... bla bla", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
} else{
             if ((event.getAction() == android.view.KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                adivinar();
                return true;
            } else
                return false;
        }

}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Valida tu editText, me imagino que en el estas ingresando puros numeros si es asi checa esto

```
if (EDIT_TEXT.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "El campo esta vacio",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                if (EDIT_TEXT.getText().toString().trim().matches("[0-9]*" && txtCode.getText().toString().trim().equals("CON QUE LO VAS A COMPARAR"))){
SI TODO SALE BIEN AQUI VA TUS ACCIONES}
```